# Pathetic Logstash performance using UDP input and Redis output

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

We are working on a Logstash configuration, which receive syslog events from various sources and the events are forwarded to Redis for queuing (without any processing or filters). Below is the configuration used.

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 514
    buffer_size => 32768
    queue_size => 300000
    workers => 10
  }
}

output {
  redis {
    host => '10.1.0.16'
    data_type => 'list'
    key => 'events'
    port => 6379
    batch => true
    batch_events => 1000
    batch_timeout => 5
    workers => 10
  }
}
```

With above configuration, we achieved 800 EPS without any UDP data loss.

In our test environment, Logstash 2.0 is deployed on win8 64 bit, i7 2.6 GHz, 8 GB RAM. Used JVM settings as XMS - 1 GB, XMX - 4 GB.

Can we improve this performance any further, by either fine tuning Logstash or fine tuning the server. Our requirement is to process events up to 50 K on a single server, without any data loss.
Also suggest the ideal system hardware for such a scenario.

Comment: Other than the config you've shown, can you describe your logstash tuning efforts?  Multiple workers?  Memory?  CPUs?

Comment: Maybe my math is wrong, but with 10 redis workers with 1000-event batches (plus maybe multiple logstash workers), it seems like you'd be buffering a lot of events in logstash before pushing them to redis.  If your input didn't match that buffer configuration well, you could be introducing delay.